# How to insert characters from a Keyboard-accessoryView right?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I'm presenting a bar with additional keys above the on-screen keyboard (`accessoryView`). I'm currently inserting the pressed characters into the `UITextField` by using `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:`, saving and restoring the `selectedRange` and temporarily disabling `scrollEnabled`. An ugly solution + Undo/Redo is not working.

Can I do this better? Is there an API for handling custom keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about all the intricacies of handling special characters, but the UITextInput protocol is what you are looking for.

Check out:

[http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%20UITextInput%20Protocol%20Reference)